# How do i POST or PUT a Set<> of links with JSON?

Tags: java, json, jpa, post, repository

My project uses the JPARepository framework, which limits my ability to debug to see what actually happens to any data sent between client and server. Thus, I am having difficulty tracking down my current issue.

I have classes that contain a ManyToMany relationship with another class. The Visual Paradigm tool automagically generates an association table between those two entities, but no Java code is generated for that association table, and no repository is made for direct requests to that table. I am currently testing a class with RestConsole to determine the exact JSON that passes between client and server. Specifically, in the class I'm struggling with, here is the declaration:

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy="provider", targetEntity=location.ServiceCoreType.class)   
@org.hibernate.annotations.Cascade({org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE, org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.LOCK}) 
@org.hibernate.annotations.LazyCollection(org.hibernate.annotations.LazyCollectionOption.TRUE)  
private java.util.Set<location.ServiceCoreType> srvcCoreType = new java.util.HashSet<location.ServiceCoreType>();
```

Other classes have ManyToOne relations with other classes, and when I POST or PUT data to save that data, my JSON for the linked class looks like:

```
"facility" : "http://localhost:8080/enums_facility/2"
```

When I last worked on this project two years ago, I recall that for the Set<> of objects I needed something like:

```
"srvcCoreType" : [ "http://localhost:8080/enums_servicecore/2", "http://localhost:8080/enums_servicecore/3" ]
```

However, when I used that on a POST, that data seemed to be ignored (i.e. no entries in the association table), but the rest of the item was created in the database. If I do a PUT, I get an error:

```
{"error":"Can not construct instance of location.ServiceCoreType: no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('http://localhost:8080/enums_servicecore/2')\n at [Source: N/A; line: -1, column: -1]"}
```

What am I missing here? How can I tell the server to link the provider to the core type?

UPDATE:
I found out that something may have happened with the model in VP, since it generated different code for the relationship in question. I then replaced that code with the original code for that relationship:

```
@ManyToMany(targetEntity=com.comporium.domain.location.ServiceCoreType.class)   
@org.hibernate.annotations.Cascade({org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.ALL}) 
@JoinTable(name="ComporiumProvider_ServiceCoreType", joinColumns={ @JoinColumn(name="ComporiumProviderID") }, inverseJoinColumns={ @JoinColumn(name="ServiceCoreTypeId") }) 
@org.hibernate.annotations.LazyCollection(org.hibernate.annotations.LazyCollectionOption.TRUE)
private java.util.Set<location.ServiceCoreType> srvcCoreType = new java.util.HashSet<location.ServiceCoreType>();
```

I can now POST this data:

```
{
    "id" : 98,
    "deleted" : "false",
    "description": "leaver",
    "modifiedBy" : "Fred" ,
    "name" : "Emca",    
    "srvcCoreType" : [ "http://localhost:8080/enums_servicecore/2" , "http://localhost:8080/enums_servicecore/3" ]
}
```

and this will create two links in the association table. Success!

Or maybe not. I can do a PUT or PASTE with one or two different links, and everything works as expected. However, if I attempt to PUT or PASTE with more links than currently exist, I get the following error:

```
{"error":"Can not construct instance of com.comporium.domain.location.ServiceCoreType: no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('http://localhost:8080/enums_servicecore/2')\n at [Source: N/A; line: -1, column: -1]"}
```

So if the provider was created without any links, there is no way to create any new links, and it is impossible to add new links. Could this be a Hibernate issue, and if so, what Hibernate flag would solve this issue. (I don't know if this has any bearing, but the original code will execute without an error - while not creating or updating any links - until I PUT or PASTE more links than currently exist. If so, I get the same error as above. How or why can it know how many exist without the @JoinTable annotation, and if it knows about the table, why does it not update those rows?)

UPDATE 2:
Found what might be causing problems. This feature works correctly in production, which is older.

Production is configured for Spring Boot v1.2.8.RELEASE / Hibernate v4, with spring.jpa.hibernate.naming_strategy=org.hibernate.cfg.DefaultNamingStrategy.

My current development is on Spring Boot v1.4.3.RELEASE / Hibernate v5, with spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl.

Could this indicate what the issue is with not being able to add new links?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution turns out to be simple. In the ServiceCoreType class, I added an empty constructor:

```
public ServiceCoreType(String json) { }
```

The webservice now works as expected/desired. I do not know exactly what the framework does behind the curtain that requires this if increasing the number of links, but I get the desired results for POST, PUT, and PATCH.